# How to read firebase analytics data in react app_

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

Stuck on this for few days. I have frontend react app and node js on backend. Frontend app have some basic analytics and log some data to it. Now, I want to read this data in my react app and show some charts. Some of react libs that exists and solve this problem use old analytics and they do not work anymore. So what is recommended way in this case? All tutorials i come across are not clear or out of date so just need general idea how to solve this problem on easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

First, firebase is quite a poor interface for reporting. Even though it stores the data properly and thoroughly, it lacks the tools for accessing it fully. Because of that, you want to [connect your FB to GA4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en) Now, there is a [reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4) interface for GA4. And Google actually [lists](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/libraries) some of the libs for the ga4 reporting api.

But it's odd when people want to access the reporting api from a client like that. You normally never access your data from a client app. It's unsecure and unneeded really. This API is normally used for ETL, but even ETL people avoid using it since GA4 now can be very easily [linked to BQ](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) which in vast majority of cases kills the need for the use of the reporting API. There are plenty of various connectors and libraries to get into BQ and further ETL your data to where you need it.

Again, in vast majority of cases displaying the app's tracking data in the app is quite a questionable decision.